# Stretching Grid inside another Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid-layout

How can i stretch horizontally "SecondGrid"?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Left" Grid.Column="0" />
    <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              Grid.Column="1" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
              Width="5" Background="#FFBCBCBC"/>
    <Label Content="Righkk" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5,0,-5,0" />


    <Grid Name="SecondGrid" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <GridSplitter 
        ResizeDirection="Rows"            
        Grid.Row="1"
        Width="Auto" 
        Height="3"
       Background="#FFBCBCBC"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        />
        <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <WebBrowser  Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <Label Content="Right" Grid.Row="2" />
    </Grid>


    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ToolBar>
                <Button Command="New" Content="New" />
                <Button Command="Open" Content="Open" />
                <Button Command="Save" Content="Save" />
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>
        <TreeView>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Level 1" IsExpanded="True">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Level 2.1" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Level 2.2" IsExpanded="True">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Level 3.1" />
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Level 3.2" />
                </TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Level 2.3" />
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your code and the SecondGrid seem to be stretching vertically. May be you could post a picture of what you are seeing and expain what you are expecting.

Comment: Yes, second grid is stretching vertically, at least on my end, as well. Maybe you intend to stretch other control and visually your are not interpreting things properly. You can always color the second grid background to give you a better perception of the elements.

Comment: I meant horizontally, sorry.

Comment: From what I recall from the sample I used yesterday, horizontally it was stretching as well, so maybe an image with the intended layout would be helpful, but I will check it again as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

i just had to remove

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```